# UWP Hide Window Title Bar controls

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit, uwp-navigation

I'm maintaining an app to show live content on big public screens.

There are 2 windows, the MainWindow that allows the user to select what content to show in the big screen, and a new window that is captured and shown in the big screen by the installed big screen driver.

The problem comes with a big customer report saying that the big screen content is showing the Title Bar controls (minimize, maximize and close) and that his big screen driver only allows him to capture entire windows.

This is a code sample about how I create the window:

```
    public Frame PublicScreenFrame { get; private set; }

    private async void CreateWindow()
    {
        var window = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
        window.RequestSize(new Size(500, 500)); //Configured resolution for the screen
        window.TitleBar.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true; //I try to make the TitleBar transparent, but the controls still there
        PublicScreenFrame = new Frame();
        ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(window, PublicScreenFrame);

        await window.TryShowAsync();
    }
```

I've found that I can make the Title Bar transparent and change the color of its controls foreground, but not make them transparent or invisible.

Is there any workaround however hacky and overengineered it is to hide the Title Bar controls?
Is there any way to make the window go to 'Windowed Fullscreen' mode in the specified resolution which would fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make the window go to 'Windowed Fullscreen' mode

For this scenario, you could refer to [Projection sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/Projection), and when you call `StartProjectingAsync` method, it will show the fullscreen window in the second monitor.

```
await ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync(rootPage.ProjectionViewPageControl.Id, thisViewId);
```

And you could also use `SwapDisplaysForViewsAsync` to switch primary window and second window.